# How to do a 301 Redirect in WebMatrix?

Tags: asp.net, seo, webmatrix

Hi I am working in WebMatrix and I am getting the error:

> `The page contains multiple
>   canonical formats.`

This happened when I ran an SEO Report on the site. I am getting the error with www.sitename.com and www.sitename.com/Default.aspx.

I know that I need to do a 301 redirect, but if possible how is this done inside of WebMatrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Response.RedirectPermanent(location)
```

or

```
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.RedirectLocation = location;
```